# Squash commits in GitHub pull request while also adding a merge commit

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I want all PRs to the main branch of my repo to have a corresponding merge commit to maintain a uniform git history. However some PRs are created with multiple commits that I do not want in the git history of my repo. I am not the one creating these PRs so I do not control the number of commits in the PR.

When I go to merge a pull request, I see the three options documented [in this chart](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/about-pull-request-merges): merge with merge commit, squash, and rebase main.

However the squash option will not add a merge commit. Is there any way to squash **and** add the merge commit? There is such an option on GitLab.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the result you want is the PR branch squashed to a single commit, then merged to the main branch with a merge commit, that is each PR creating two commits in history? Why would you want this?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? What problem does not keeping the original commits solve? Because removing them certainly creates new problems like making [git bisect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVFF9dms9Oc) less useful, higher review burden, etc.

Comment: I want this because the merge commit itself contains the information that this was a merge of a feature branch on main. git history visualization tools such as `tig` use these to display the history. I don't like rebase or pure squash because it does not maintain the information that the commit was a merged PR (visually). On the other hand, contributors sometimes include useless commits. For example 'temp', or multiple commits to fix issues found on code review. I don't want these appearing in main's git history.

Comment: So you're attempting to use squash as a deodorant to cover up the bad smell from a stinking version history... If people send pull requests with commit messages like "temp" then the *proper remedy* is to give feedback that that is unacceptable and require the pull request creator to fix this and resubmit with a decent version history. "Helping" the contributor by doing an automatic squash would be a short sighted [bear's service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bear_and_the_Gardener) that in the long run prevents the contributor from learning and improving.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to squash and add the merge commit?

No.

There is no such option in **git** to actually "merge" and "squash" at the same time. Squashing is an option for "rebase".

When **GitHub** merges PRs with squashing it actually rebases the PR branch on `master` branch with squashing. That's why `Squash and merge` GitHub option doesn't make a "merge commit".

Comment: It's incorrect to say git does not support this. If I had access to their branch, I could switch to that branch, `git rebase -i`, squash all but one commit, then merge the branch with `git merge --no-ff`. This is actually a typical workflow in many companies, including two large companies that I have worked for in the past. Second, this is an option supported by Gitlab so it's obviously possible.

Comment: You are right. I mean there is no such option as an atomic operation, but you still do it as a set of different steps: rebase with squash and merge. The problem for vendors such GitHub and GitLab - which set of operations is more common for most developers to implement it as a default behaviour in their (vendors) products.

Answer (score 0):

Either `git merge --squash` or `git rebase --interactive`
None of them can mark the merge relationship at the same time,Because it doesn't make sense.
squash merge's parent commit just is HEAD^1 .

Comment: If I had access to their branch, I could switch to that branch, `git rebase -i`, squash all but one commit, then merge the feature branch with `git merge --no-ff`. This is actually a typical workflow in many companies, including two large companies that I have worked for in the past. Second, this is an option supported by Gitlab so it's obviously possible.